# c# привязка событий на несколько элементов

Tags: c#

как привязать событие на несколько элементов? 
мне нужно например добавить событие click на несколько уже существующих контролов, 
как в Jquery

```
$(".element").click(function(){
    if(this.что_то_там){

    }
})
```

и как использовать ссылку на текущий объект this внутри функции?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Вам нужно реализовать паттерн Observer. Используйте делегаты. Почему я не могу написать ответ на этот вопрос? могу только комментировать

Answer (score 4):

Ну например при помощи цикла, если у вас есть список элементов:

```
foreach (var t in runningTasks)
    t.Completed += result => results.Add(result);
```